# drawing an n-gon with equilateral triangles on each side

Tags: polygon, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Using Turtle graphics, I need to write a function f(n,r)

This function should draw a regular polygon with n sides.  The length of each side should be r.  It should work for any n

Then I need to write a function g(n,r) which draws the same polygon, and then draws an outward pointing equilateral triangle on each side of polygon. One side of the triangle is the same as the side of the polygon.

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()

def f(n, r):
    for i in range(n):
        t.forward(r)
        t.right(360/n)

def g(n, r):
    for i in range(n):
        t.forward(r)
        t.right(360/n)
        for j in range(3):
            t.forward(r)
            t.left(120)

n = # Your number here
r = # Your number here
f(n, r)
g(n, r)
```

Comment: The fact that you are trying to help others in programming is amazing, but there are 2 problems with your answer. First is that the question itself was not a question and just a person asking for their work to be done for them. Secondly, your answer is lacking detail and explanations, please focus on that part. If you can't think of anything to explain more with your answers try thinking that you are teaching a 5 year old and that you have to explain every step in your response in order for him to understand. Have a nice day!